# Is the number triple-6 good, bad, or neutral in Judaism?

Tags: number, gematria-numerology

Is the number triple-6 good, bad, or neutral in Judaism?

How about numeric variations and combinations such as 216?

I know that 18 means 'life' due to Gematria calculations.

Comment: May be of interest: "[Six Six Six](http://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/277/Q1/)"( which is a follow up to "[Meah Shearim](http://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/274/Q1/)", both from the "Ask The Rabbi" section, at the Ohr Somayach website).

Comment: Meaningless, IINM.

Comment: Related( Re: 216): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6606/shisha-asar-umatayim-mi-yodeya .

Comment: How is that an improvement in formatting?

Comment: Because I wanted the title to sound more decent.

Comment: It is 1000+666 that is the bad number in Judaism.  The height of Shabbati Zevi's popularity by the Julian/Gregorian calender; 5426 in the Hebrew calendar.

Comment: וַיְהִי מִשְׁקַל הַזָּהָב אֲשֶׁר־בָּא לִשְׁלֹמֹה בְּשָׁנָה אֶחָת שֵׁשׁ מֵאוֹת שִׁשִּׁים וָשֵׁשׁ 
כִּכַּר זָהָב: מלכים א י:יד. And the weight of the gold that came to Shlomo in one year was 666 ingots.

Comment: http://dafyomireview.com/431

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69506

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This number has, to the best of my knowledge, no significance whatsoever in Judaism.

You can search according to gematria [here](http://thetrugmans.com/word-and-gematria-search/) but, as my teacher Rabbi Tzvi Aryeh Rosenfeld z'l said in a shiur, the average person shouldn't really come up with their own gematrios, generally speaking, and expect anything from them.

You will find that there are many gematrios with both good and bad implications for practically every value.

Comment: No source, but that's because there isn't one.

Comment: http://kabbalahsecrets.com/?p=2265 see this

Comment: I Kings 10:14 states that King Solomon used 666 talents of gold to build the First Temple. (A biblical "talent" is an ~80 lb block.) Seems to be a neutral coincidence. Gold has been used for a lot of good things, as well as a lot of bad things.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the number 666 have no significant tendency in Hebrew, and there for in Hebrew and Jewish Gematria. By checking both Hebrew genatria on http://www.c2kb.com/gematria/?word=666 and on Gematrix: http://www.gematrix.org/?word=666 shows no higher amount of results for each side.

Comment: מאה שערים lol .

Comment: @DoubleAA, that's how we know it's a good number in Judaism. :)

Answer (score -5):

666 is very significant in two locations in Genesis.

First, in the beginning of creation, the values for light, dark, day and night add together into the sum 666. אור=207, חשך=328,יום=56, לילה=75. Though חשך commonly is written with a ״ו״ (vav), in the creation account it isn't.

Second, when Joseph becomes second in command of Egypt, Pharaoh renames him צפנת פנעח. The value of this name is 828. He demands Benjamin come down to Egypt. בנימין has a value of 162. 828-162=666. In regard to what 666 is in creation, it then fits in context of the Joseph narrative and the fulfillment of his final dream before his brothers threw him into the pit.

Comment: Why is the fact that those gematrias work out to 666 "very significant"? Especially the one with subtraction. I've almost never seen subtraction used in gematrias where it's not obviously relevant.

Comment: Hey Daniel. Perhaps "very" is a relative term. However, I find it significant in the sense that the four elements included in the first day add to 666. In my judgment that is noteworthy. Debate me if you disagree.

Comment: Also, how do you determine what is "obviously relevant" and what isn't? To me, passing a connection off as irrelevant is cutting yourself short from a potential insight.

Comment: except that as far as I can tell on a quick read, the word choshech never appears in Genesis 1. It always has a prefix (a vav, a hey or a vav-lamed) so making a point about its not being spelled with a vav internally is undermined by its use of other letters and then the sum reached is inaccurate.

Comment: Why is it significant that the four elements of the first day add up to 666 (even though they don't as Danno points out)? I'm sure I could find plenty of combinations of words in the Torah whose gematria adds up to pretty much any number. If we didn't pass connections off as irrelevant, we'd be overloaded with infinitely many "insights" that don't really do us any good.

Comment: We need an "unclear what you're answering" flag.

Comment: I don't understand why the point on prefixes negates what I've said. The prefix changes multiple times whereas the three letters in choshech remain. Don't see why we need to add up those prefixes as well.

Comment: Danny, my answer to the original question is that it's not bad. I thought that was implied, sorry. I'd imagine bringing forces of light and darkness together is a good thing, but who's to say?