# My current reputation is 666. Am I over on Machashefah Lo tichayah?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I just noticed that my reputation is standing at 666. Does this number have the same demonic connotations in Judaism that it does in Christianity? And if so, am I potentially violating issurim regarding shedim, nichush, and kishuf?

***UPDATE:*** I am no longer at 666 reputation, but the question still stands: should I or other posters in the future actively remove the reputation of 666 by engaging in downvotes? Is failing to do so when noticing the number considered a passive acceptance? Is it like walking by an uncovered pit that I co-own with Stack Exchange? Are there other numbers to actively avoid, like 344 - SHMaD?

Properly sourced answers only, please.

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the number triple-6 good, bad, or neutral in Judaism?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31399/is-the-number-triple-6-good-bad-or-neutral-in-judaism)

Comment: I appreciate the downvotes - I intepret them as a sign that someone is trying to KEEP my reputation at 666. I suppose this means that they approve, and want to reassure me that there is no need to suspect an aveirah in this case.

Answer (score 2):

666 is Gematria תסור, meaning "to turn away".

Devarim 17:11 says:

לא תסור מן הדבר אשר יגידו לך ימין ושמאל

"Don't turn away from what they say about you, right or left.

The reputation number you receive is mainly gained by other people voting for you. (Yes, I know that you get points for answering others and other items, but, in truth, if others never vote for you in any way, you wouldn't remain on M.Y.) So, you gained the 666 by what others say about you.

Thus, you are not allowed to turn from that number in either direction. No one can upvote you nor downvote you either. 666 is the number that you must stay at as long as you remain a M.Y. member.

Since, I see that your reputation is now above that, then, yes, you have transgressed a major *aveira*, and it looks like you may have done this intentionally. Oy vey, Isaac! See verse 12 to find out what should happen to you. I don't know if the moderators here have the same authority as the Bet Din or Kohen Gadol. We'll have to let them decide.

Comment: Is THAT why we have three mods?

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt - I did not know that. Who are they? I know that DoubleAA is one. Who are the others?

Comment: @DanF http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators

Comment: re your last sentence: actually we have the powers of Melekh around here. I assume you stand up to honor us every time we ping you, right? If not, SUSPENSION!!!

Comment: @DoubleAA - Considering that you do most of the pinging, does that make you Melech Malchei Hamlachim?

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt - 3 mods ... you may have a point, here.