# Shisha Veshishim Ushesh Meot (666) - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows six hundred sixty-six?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible.*

*At some point between twenty-four hours and a few days from now, I will:*

- *Vote up all interesting, relevant answers.*
- *Accept what I consider the "best" answer.*

Related.
https://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/277/Q1/
And.    [My current reputation is 666. Am I over on Machashefah Lo tichayah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55579/5120)

Comment: Gematria of Meah Shearim?

Comment: @Uber_Chacham it seems that is an answer https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/666_(מספר) also see https://www.sefaria.org/II_Chronicles.9.13 ,  https://www.sefaria.org/Ezra.2.13 and https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.10.14

Comment: Wow... I was just making that up

Comment: Also related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31399/5120

Comment: Why skip hundreds of numbers instead of continuing in order? Patience is a virtue.

Comment: @msh210 after reading the article of the first link (in the op) I wanted to find a more authoritative source, I did not find here for 666 so I asked myself, (are you hinting that zrizus (my nickname) is not (a virtue)?)

Comment: @hazoriz You have ruined the mi yodeya series

Comment: @JoshuaPearl why do you say so?

Comment: @hazoriz The series has been going in order from 1 until 346 and you have left out 347-665, thus ruining the order.

Comment: https://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/277/Q1/

Answer (score 8):

Ezra 2:13

בְּנֵי֙ אֲדֹ֣נִיקָ֔ם שֵׁ֥שׁ מֵא֖וֹת שִׁשִּׁ֥ים וְשִׁשָּֽׁה:
The children of Adonikam were six hundred sixty-six.

Answer (score 6):

It's the amount of gold Shlomo Hamelech received every year.

[Melachim I 10:14](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.10.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> וַֽיְהִי֙ מִשְׁקַ֣ל הַזָּהָ֔ב אֲשֶׁר־בָּ֥א לִשְׁלֹמֹ֖ה בְּשָׁנָ֣ה
> אֶחָ֑ת שֵׁ֥שׁ מֵא֛וֹת שִׁשִּׁ֥ים וָשֵׁ֖שׁ כִּכַּ֥ר זָהָֽב׃
>
> The weight of the gold which Solomon received every year was 666
> talents of gold.

This is from a comment by [moses](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1441/moses) on [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31399/21984) post about the significance of 666 in Judaism.

Answer (score 5):

Six hundred sixty-six is the common name of the renowned hemshech of 61 Chassidic discourses said by the fifth Lubavitcher Rebbe, Rabbi Shalom Dov Ber which he began saying in the year 5666. It’s formal name is Yom Tov Shel Rosh HaShanah.

It marks a new tekufah in the Chassidic world and discusses the ultimate point of creation.

[image: Title Page of 666]

[image: Preface to first edition]

Answer (score 2):

666 is gematria of "yom shishi", sixth day, where in Genesis 1:31 is written "yom hashishi", the sixth day, by which the name of God appears to be present in the initial letters of "yom hashishi vay'chullu hashamayim".